# Having issues using proper syntax for multidimensional arrays in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays, json, multidimensional-array

There are a multitude of similar questions like this one -- I've read nearly all of them on Stack and haven't been able to wrap my head around it.

I'm decoding a json file using CURL. The URL I'm retrieving contents from is https://api.mojang.com/user/profiles/e6e37a93864f496383ba362df30f4792/names.

After I convert the array to a PHP array correctly, I'm attempting to return the last item in the PHP array.

I've attempted to use array_pop but I couldn't get it to work. I resorted to counting the total rows in the array, and referencing that last row using the count.

```
    $data = json_decode($output);

    $count = count($data);

    return $data[$count]['name'];`
```

I've even attempted to do

```
    return $data[$count]['name']->name; // OR...

    return $data[$count]->name;
```

This is because

```
    return $data[0]->name;
```

returns "Eli_Silveraxe", a value from the array, but not the last value. None of these options have worked for me, and it's only become more frustrating because I can return Eli_Silveraxe, but not "Malfunction", which is what SHOULD be returning.

Can you please help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this please

```
$data = json_decode($output, true);
$count = count($data) - 1;
return $data[$count]['name'];
```

Comment: This does return an item from the array, but not the last array item's 'name'. This returns 'Eli_Silveraxe'. Taking a look at the url with the JSON array, 'Malfunction' would be the desired return because it's the last array item's 'name'.

Comment: if you make this? $count = count($data) ; what do you retrieve? @x0y

Comment: I've tried that as well, actually. It doesn't return anything.

Comment: Alessandro, I just combined what you suggested with a `return $data[$count]['name'];` and it returns "Malfunction" successfully! Would this be proper syntax?

Comment: yes I update the answer! Glad to help you! the problem was in json_decode because the second parameter help you to get associative array @x0y Accept the answer to help other guys with your same problem

Answer (score 0):

The last item in the array has index of `count - 1`, therefore you need this:

```
$data = json_decode($output);
$count = count($data);
return $data[$count - 1]->name;
```

Note that you don't need to pass the second parameter to the `json_decode` (or pass `false`) to get objects in your `$data`.  Alternatively, pass `true` and use associative array syntax:

```
$data = json_decode($output, true);
$count = count($data);
return $data[$count - 1]['name'];
```